# DOMPDF in joomla, error handling and email

Tags: php, pdf, phpmailer, dompdf, joomla3.1

I am having some trouble making a pdf attachment from dompdf successfully attach to an email.
The pdf document just says its malformed, not giving me any kind of error, however when i go directly to the link, the pdf downloads and loads successfully.

The email sends fine so the following line is all i can see that can possibly cause an issue.

`$mailer->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=finish&format=pdf&tmpl=component&data='.$id.'&Itemid='.$Itemid)),'Assessment.pdf');`

The item id and id are loading from the following code

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $menu = $app->getMenu();
        $menuItem = $menu->getItems( 'link', 'index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=core', true );
        $Itemid = $menuItem->id;
$id = JRequest::getVar('assessmentId',null,'get');
```

This is all for the actual email creation, it does send an email with an attached pdf, however the pdf is malformed.

The view.pdf.php file runs as well the only difference between them is that the id loads the data rather then a session.

```
$data = JRequest::getVar('data',false,'get');
                if($data!==false){
                        //$data = urldecode($data);
                        //$data = json_decode($data);
                        $this->curData = array('id'=>$data,'data'=>$model->getAssessment($data));
                }else{
                        $this->curData = $session->get('core_value_assessment');
                }
```

Comment: Save the PDF from the email and open it in a text editor. Often a corrupted PDF is due to PHP notices/warnings getting caught in the output stream.

Comment: Can't believe i didn't think to try that..... thanks!

Comment: It's an easy one to miss. You don't necessarily expect PHP notices/warnings to be captured in the output stream. We've been trying to make changes to avoid that, though it still seems to be a problem.

Comment: Ended up not being it, just a blank file >.> with maximum reporting too.

Comment: So the PDF created is totally blank? If you do the same to grab the PDF but then send it to the browser (e.g. `echo file_get_contents(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=finish&format=pdf&tmpl=component&data='.$id.'&Itemid='.$Itemid))`) what do you see?

Comment: Well that's the thing, that page itself going into a "normal" view, meaning direct access works without a hitch. So far I have recoded it from scratch 3-4 times and get the same result, my next step is to look into the library Joomla uses emails (PHPMailer) and see if this is a bug in it...

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. You could try saving the PDF instead of attaching it to the email, something so you can see what's being attached to the email. Then, yeah, the next step is looking at PHPMailer. Anything useful in the logs?

Comment: Unable to see anything in the logs. I will continue looking into this. There are many things that I cannot figure an explanation for right now but all I can hope for is that I will see something wrong in the code and facepalm soon ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being an "error" or rather then error, strange behavior from JRoute. It changes & to `&amp;` automatically, witch being system parameters was causing it to try to route to the default view rather then the one I needed. The solution was to only use JRoute to get the menu itemid `JRoute::_('index.php?Itemid=%%%')`. This way it would get the proper path and you can add any extra parameters after.

The reason this was hard to diagnose is blind trust in JRoute as I never ran into this anywhere else. So because of that I never considered that such a straight forward route would not even go to the right view.

So to anyone else who has this problem or something similar, the trick is that since it is being generated for an email, pull that portion of the code out and print it in a view to see how its generating the link.

Comment: I'm sorry, _"It changes & to &"_? Now, _that's_ innovation!

Comment: looks like it auto changed it on me :D i meant `&amp;`. Also JRoute "should" handle urlencode automatically.

Answer (score 0):

domPDF throws exception in the event of error. Have you tried wrapping your code that produces the PDF with `try catch`?

e.g.

```
<?php

require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

try
{
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html('YOUR PDF HTML GOES HERE');
    $dompdf->set_paper("a4", "portrait");
    $dompdf->render();

    // $dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
    $fp = fopen('test.pdf', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $dompdf->output());
    fclose($fp);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // log $e->getMessage() to file to see if any error(s) are occuring
}

?>
```

Comment: This is using a Joomla implementation of domPDF, so this is won't work in this situation. Also, the issue is only with sending an email, not generating a PDF (that works fine). However try/catch is a good idea to try, I would upvote but I wasted all my rep on the bounty....

Answer (score 0):

This may sound stupid, but you never know what can be the heart of the matter.

Check if the script `index.php?option=com_helloworld&view=finish&format=pdf...` does not generate any PHP errors int it's output.

Open the produced file in a text editor, and make sure it begins with sort of a binary header, not a few lines like `<b>Notice:</b> . . .` or such.